# Flutter app does not run on release mode and only shows white screen

Tags: flutter, release

I saw my app works well on emulator and built an apk to test it on my phone. It only showed white screen and worked nothing.

I found somehow `flutter run -v` command, and running this command make my emulator also shows only white screen.

The whole log of the command is uploaded [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112345), and the whole txt file for log can be found in the end of the issue.

What is the usual reason of the problem ? I am still trying but not finding answer.

If there is any code or information I should post here please tell me and I will immediately do.

Comment: Permissions are missing.

Comment: @Creator I added internet_connection_state permission and internet permission already. is there anything that I am missing ? My app does not use any gps, camera, etc except fireebase module

Comment: Are you using remote config?

Comment: @Creator no Im not

Answer (score 2):

add internet permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file
android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but im afraid to say that it does not work :(